# React Components re renders (making the api call again) when going back from some route to homepage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What could cause this re rendering of the component. To my understanding react preserve the previous page when going to another page using the LINK tag?

Live link: Thethirdfront.vercel.app
[www.github.com/saurabhje/Truly-Trustable-News](http://www.github.com/saurabhje/Truly-Trustable-News)

Homepage Component

```
const Homepage = () => {
  const [header, setHeader] = useState([]);
  const [imageindex, setImageindex] = useState(0);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const increaseIndex = () => {
    setImageindex((imageindex + 1) % header.length);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${baseurl}`);
        setHeader(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const imageTransition = setTimeout(increaseIndex, 4000);
    return () => clearTimeout(imageTransition);
  }, [imageindex, header]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>The Third Front</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Homepage of a satirical news blog" />
      </Helmet>
      <AbsoluteNavbar className="absnav">
        <Navbar />
      </AbsoluteNavbar>
      {error && <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</p>}
      <div className="header-wrapper">
        {header &&
          header.map((index) => (
            <Link
              to={`/news/${index.slug}`}
              className="header"
              key={index.img.src}
              style={{ translate: `${-100 * imageindex}%` }}
            >
              <div
                className="background-layer"
                style={{
                  backgroundImage: index
                    ? `linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), url(${index.img.src})`
                    : "",
                  backgroundPosition: index.img.position
                    ? `${index.img.position}`
                    : "center",
                }}
              ></div>
              <div className="text-layer">
                <Hero heading={index.heading} author={index.author} />
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
      </div>
      <MainContent />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

MAINCONTENT COMPONENT

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./main-content.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const baseurl = import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL;


const MainContent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [sidebardata, setSidebardata] = useState([])
  const [mobileView, setMobileView] = useState();
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [cat, setCat] = useState();
  const [catdata, setCatdata] = useState([])
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const fetchInfo = async() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const link = cat? `${baseurl}/?page=${page}&cat=${cat}`: `${baseurl}/?page=${page}`
    axios
      .get(link)
      .then((response) => {
        setData((prevNews) => [...prevNews, ...response.data]);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError("Error fetching data:", error);
      });
  };

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  const handleResize = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1080) {
      setMobileView(true);
    } else {
      setMobileView(false);
    }
  };

  const handleCatchange = (e) =>{
    setCat(e.target.value)
    setPage(1);
    setData([]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInfo();
  }, [page, cat]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const sidebarlink = `${baseurl}/sidebar`;
    axios
      .get(sidebarlink)
      .then((response) => {
        setSidebardata((prevNews) => [...prevNews, ...response.data]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError("Error fetching sidebar data:", error);
      });
    axios
    .get(`${baseurl}/categories`)
    .then((response) => {
      setCatdata(response.data)
    })
    handleResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="main">
    {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      <div className="content-wrap">
        <div className="select">
          <h2>Sort News By categories</h2>
          <select  onChange={handleCatchange}> 
              <option value="">All</option>
              {catdata.map((e, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={e.title}>{e.title}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          {data.map((e, index) => {
            const itemWrapClass = index % 2 === 0 ? "itemwrap1" : "itemwrap2";
            return (
              <Link to={`/news/${e.slug}`} className="item" key={index}>
                <div className={itemWrapClass}>
                    <div className="gradient">
                    <img id="img" src={e.img.src} alt="News Image" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="heading-p">
                    <hr />
                    <h2>{e.heading}</h2>
                    <p>
                      {e.subheading}
                    </p>
                    <div className="catog">
                      Categories:
                      {e.category ? (
                        e.category.map((cat) => (
                          <span className='px-1 text-sky' key={cat._id}>{cat.title}</span>
                        ))
                      ) : (
                        <span>No categories available</span>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Link>
            );
          })}
          <div className="loading-wrap">
            {loading ? (
              <div className="lds-ring">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <button id="loadmore" onClick={handleLoadMore}>
                Load More
              </button>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainContent;
```

Page corresponding to /news/slug

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "../navbar/navbar";
import Footer from "../footer";
import "./newspage.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
const baseurl = import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL;

const Newspage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const { slug } = useParams();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${baseurl}/news/${slug}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data[0]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        setData(null);
      });
  });

  const renderHtmlContent = (html) => {
    return { __html: html };
  };

  if (!data) {
    throw new Error("Data not found");
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>{data.heading}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="News page" />
      </Helmet>
      <div
        className="header"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: data.img ? `url(${data.img.src})` : "",
          backgroundPosition: data.img ? `${data.img.position}` : "center",
        }}
      >
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <div className="newsbody">
        <div className="news-hero-text">
          <h1>{data.heading}</h1>
          <p className="subheading">{data.subheading}</p>
          <p>
            <em>{data.author}</em>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Newspage;
```

React Router

```
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import Homepage from './homepage/homepage';
import Newspage from './newspage/newspage';

const Router = () =>{
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Homepage/>
    },
    {
      path: "/news/:slug",
      element: <Newspage/>,
      errorElement: <NotFound/>
    },

  ]);
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default Router;
```

Comment: *To my understanding react preserve the previous page when going to another page using the LINK tag* - do you have a source for that, I've never heard of it

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect will be executed every time that component is rendered. When you navigate away, it is removed from the DOM. When you come back, it renders (thus the useEffect will be executed).

If you only want it to load once, and still be available on later renders, you need to use something like redux to store the data at a higher level. You can add a boolean value like `hasLoaded` and set it to true when the data is fetched.

Then you can update your useEffect to only fetch when `!hasLoaded`.